# 2x4s in hall closet

Tags: walls, framing

I am sawing an opening in the side of my protruding hall closet because it's the only place in my apartment that has room for a wine fridge.

My plan was to find out where the framing was after punching an inspection hole, then saw through the 2x4s. I was surprised to see that there are doubled up 2x4s instead.

Above this closet is the washer/dryer, so could this wall be load-bearing?

[image: progress]

Diagram shows outline of fridge plus where the posts are located. I want to remove the baseboard and have the front of the fridge flush with the wall.

Comment: Are you sure it's 4x4s, and not doubled up 2x4s?

Comment: What's the measurement between the two studs? It looks as if you could fit the fridge if you had a few more inches. Instead of cutting through just notch each side to allow it to fit.

Comment: Just curious, how did you determine those studs are 4x4's?  Nothing in the photo would indicate that.

Comment: Thanks @batsplatserson - I ripped back the drywall inside the closet to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Ecnerwal, the closet is likely an architectural feature designed around the necessity of the location of load bearing members. Not to worry though, you could remove the entire drywall section (you will be mudding, taping, and sanding anyway) and install new structural studs and jack-studs to support a header which spans the opening. Consult a framing carpenter or builder.

Answer (score 1):

What's above your apartment? I'd tend to suspect that cutting these might result it whatever it is being in your apartment, and a rather large bill for fixing the building. Whether it's 4x4's or doubled 2x4s, the only reason to build like this is to hold up a structural load, IME.

Practically speaking, your wine would probably be better off in the closet with wall put back and the door closed - dark is a good thing for it.

Comment: thanks Ecnerwal, sounds like you are right but don't you think it's weird that a protruding closet would be a load bearing wall?

Comment: If it isn't a load bearing wall, maybe it was reinforced because there's a heavy heating / air conditioning unit on the roof above.

Comment: There is a washer dryer directly above and bathroom further back.

Comment: The closet may be there mostly to support the load, with the function of "closet" being secondary.